# Playing separate videos on different monitors on linux?

Tags: ubuntu, video, mplayer, x264

I'm building a system for a friend's work that has four different videos playing on a loop on different monitors in the business. I've currently set up a Ubuntu 12.04 box with a Radeon HD7850 and am wondering what's the most effective way to automate playing of the content. The videos have to be set up on a loop but mplayer when you use the display flag is not displaying on the correct monitor. The monitors are all 1080p capable TVs. Given that I'll be playing 1080p mkv files on the different monitors and the machine has an i5 and 8GB of RAM, should it be able to play the files simultaneously on the different machines fluidly, and what should I do to configure mplayer appropriately? if you have another suggestion over using the current setup I'd like to hear it as my friend doesn't mind spending a bit of money to play the content on the different displays but ideally he'd only like to have to manage/administer one machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) for all of my video needs.  I'm not sure how to accomplish what you are asking using the command line, but why not set this up in a GUI, then drag the windows to the screens you want them?